# Multiple Filter Listview C#

Tags: c#, wpf

So i have two Textboxes where the user can Filter either the BoxNumber or Barcode in a ListView. Now i want to use multiple filtering, however one of them is not working without any error. If i comment one of them out the other one is working why?

```
        CollectionView view = (CollectionView)CollectionViewSource.GetDefaultView(parkingListe.ItemsSource);
        view.Filter = UserFilter;
        view.Filter = UserFilter_box;




        //Text Search (Barcode Search) 
        private bool UserFilter(object item)
        {
            if (String.IsNullOrEmpty(txtFilter.Text))
                return true;
            else
                return ((item as ParkingClass).parking_barcode.IndexOf(txtFilter.Text, StringComparison.OrdinalIgnoreCase) >= 0);
  
        }

        //Box Search (Box Inhalt Search)
        private bool UserFilter_box(object item)
        {
            if (String.IsNullOrEmpty(boxFilter.Text))
                return true;
            else
                return ((item as ParkingClass).parking_box.IndexOf(boxFilter.Text, StringComparison.OrdinalIgnoreCase) >= 0);
        }
```

Comment: If you can add the error message that will help us try to help you.

Comment: There is no error, everything is compiling. But if I have redundant Filters, one of them is not working. If I comment one out the other one is working fine.

Answer (score 2):

[CollectionView.Filter](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.windows.data.collectionview.filter?view=windowsdesktop-7.0#system-windows-data-collectionview-filter) can only be set with one filter Predicate so when you assign it twice you're just changing the previous filter value.

You should combine both methods into a single filter function for the `CollectionView`